# Terminate a c++ string

Tags: c++, string

Is there a way to terminate a C++ string at any arbitary location. This is very easy in C as we can just insert a null character wherever we want. But how can the same be achieved in C++ String.

For example, Let's consider the following example,

```
string str = "This is Stack OverflowXXXX";
```

Now I want to terminate this string so that I would get "This is Stack Overflow".

Comment: That question is simply answered by reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: Try ::resize but I dont know whether it just terminates at the reduced size

Answer (score 2):

Yep! Use [`string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase):

```
str.erase(k);
```

will erase all characters from position `k` forward. There's no way to "undo" this to get those characters back, though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will this also decrease the size of the string? length would also get updated?

Comment: ... or `resize(newsize)`. Just to make it a bit clearer, `k` in the answer is an integer indicating the position, not an iterator.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas But you can use iterators as well: `str.erase( iter, str.end() )`.

Comment: @James correct, but if you use a single argument and it is an iterator it will erase a single character.